# Cannot create or clear message alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have a unread message counter (number). Upon entering the chatroom, the unread messages will be marked as read and counter = 0.

Right now, the click event works (checked with console.log) but somehow I cant seem to mark read or mark unread for the messages and their alerts.

***NOTE: After the updated answer**

**roomDetail.js - for submitting message + create alert**

```
Template.roomDetail.events({
  'submit form': function(template) {
      var message = template.find('input').value;  
      var roomId = this._id; 
      Messages.insert({           
         roomId    : Router.current().params._id, //changed from roomId
         msg       : message,
         submitted : new Date().getTime()
      });
      template.find('input').value = '';
      createMessageAlert(messageId, roomId, message); //changed this
   }
});
```

**allRooms.js - for click into room**

```
Template.allRooms.events({
   'click .enterRoom': function() {
      Meteor.call("markAlertsAsRead", { roomId: this._id }); 
   }
});
```

**Collections**

```
//shifted all to alerts.js collection file
Messages = new Mongo.Collection("messages");
   createMessageAlert = function(messageId, roomId, message){
      if (message) {
         if ( message.user !== Meteor.userId() ){     
            Alerts.insert({
               roomId        : Router.current().params._id, //roomId doesnt work, messages get logged but do not appear
               messageId     : messageId,  //message._id,
               read          : false
            });
         }
      }
   };

Meteor.methods({
   markAlertsAsRead: function(roomId, options){
      Alerts.update({ roomId: options.roomId }, {$set:{ read:true }},{ multi:true }); //says options is undefined
   } 
});
```

Comment: There are still two problems, markalertsasread method should have only one param: options. And you are not defining messageid in the event helper. Both are in my code samples, please check.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not finding the Alerts to update because you selecting the wrong id in the update. You are now looking for an alert with an Id beloninging to a room.

```
Template.allRooms.events({
   //'click a': function() {
   'click .enterRoom': function() {

      Alerts.update(this._id, { $set: {read: true}} );//<--- first argument is the selector (should be an Alert id)
      console.log("you clicked .enterRoom");
   }
});
```

I think it should be like this. Find an alert that has a roomId that equals the current Id.

```
Template.allRooms.events({
   //'click a': function() {
   'click .enterRoom': function() {

      Alerts.update({roomId: this._id}, { $set: {read: true}} );//<--- now assuming this._id is a roomId
      console.log("you clicked .enterRoom");
   }
});
```

## update

When reproducting some of your code I noticed some "unsafe" errors. Apparently you can no longer do the update as mentioned above from the client so you have to call a server method (or loop through all the alerts to find their _id).

Below I'm calling a server method (from client)

```
Template.allRooms.events({
   //'click a': function() {
   'click .enterRoom': function() {

      Meteor.call("markAlertsAsRead", {roomId:this._id});//<-- Call a server function
      console.log("you clicked .enterRoom");
   }
});
```

Then in the server you can use a method like this

```
Meteor.methods({ 
  markAlertsAsRead:function(options){ 
     Alerts.update({roomId:options.roomId}, {$set:{
       read:true
     }},{multi:true});//<-- Multi to update all that match the selector

  } 
});
```

Also notice the **multi** option. This is needed because it will otherwise only update the first match for the selector.

## update 2

Updated your createmessagealert function and roomdetail event handler

```
Template.roomDetail.events({
  'submit form': function(event, template) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var message = template.find('input').value;
      var roomId = this._id;

      var messageId = Messages.insert({
         roomId    : roomId,
         msg       : message,
         submitted : new Date().getTime()
      });
      template.find('input').value = '';
      createMessageAlert(messageId, roomId, message);
   }
});


createMessageAlert = function(messageId, roomId, message){
  Alerts.insert({
     roomId        : roomId,
     messageId     : messageId,
     read          : false
  });
};
```

You do not need to observe added for the message collection since you are already calling createMessageAlert manually.

Comment: Are you subscribing to Alerts?

Comment: Also, did you check if the createMessageAlert is being called at all?

Comment: Hi Jan, sorry about delay. I did not subscribe as `null` publication is global => hence no need to subscribe?. I added console.log to `Messages.find().observe({` but no console.log if i insert it under `Alerts.insert`. There is console.log message when I post message. However the count still does not clear nor update. Whenever I enter room, the console.log gets triggered too.

Comment: This one will never work "createMessageAlert(message);" because you are passing a message in the id parameters' place.

Comment: I think you should split up your code to isolate the problem or console log parameters and values everywhere.

Comment: @Thinkerer after reproducing your situation (sort of) I found some issues. Most notable the {multi} option.

Comment: To be honest I don't know since I've never used the null publish. But it is indeed what I used to test your code.

Comment: I used null because thats what someone guided me to. I originally tried to do a normal publish subscribe with a meteor method. https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/blob/master/lib/collections/comments.js

Comment: I followed the instructions. Been getting this error. `Exception while invoking method markAlertsAsRead. TypeError: Cannot read property roomId of undefined`. Which means `option` is undefined for `options.roomId`. Do we need it? I tried to add `check(options, Object)` but match failed. (probably wrong match type).

Comment: Maybe if you post the code you have now in your question then we can locate the problem.

Comment: I tried the code above. Also changed roomid to the router params to enable messages to be logged and appear. However the alerts are still not appearing, and im not sure if they are cleared on clicking to enter the room. Could it be a pub/sub issue? I logged the messages and they are inserted into the DB correctly.

Comment: Did you try logging alert insertion? To make sure you can also use the Shell command meteor mongo to look into mongodb directly.

Comment: I tried logging on the collection.js. SO when i send message, there is a result logged with an alertId. SO puzzling, the unread alert counter still doesnt show up.

Comment: There is no code present that let's me diagnose that problem. Perhaps you can start a new question to resolve this? This here is getting kind of messy

Comment: Thanks Jan, posted here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766843/alerts-are-inserted-but-not-showing-up