# Alerts are inserted but not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

Im working on a unread counter for messages and have alert collection and messages collection.

Issue now is console log shows alerts are attached to messsage, however the counter does not show up. Typing `Alerts.find().count();` in console3e gives 0.

**template counter + click to clear alerts**

```
//helper 
   alertCount: function(){
      return Alerts.find({ userId: Meteor.userId(), read: false }).count();
   }
//event 
   'click .enterRoom': function() {
      Meteor.call('markAlertsAsRead', { roomId: this._id }); 
   }
```

**attach alert when submit message**

```
  'submit form': function(e, template) {  
      e.preventDefault();
      var message = template.find('input').value;  
      var roomId = this._id; 
      var messageId = Messages.insert ({ 
         roomId    : Router.current().params._id, 
         msg       : message,
         userId    : Meteor.user()._id,
      });
      template.find('input').value = '';
      createMessageAlert(messageId, roomId, message);

      var insertedMessage = Messages.findOne(messageId);
      console.log(insertedMessage + messageId); //logs msg + alert 
   }
```

**in alert.js collection**

```
Meteor.methods({
   markAlertsAsRead: function(options){ 
      check(options, Object);
      Alerts.update({ roomId: options.roomId }, { $set:{ read: true } }, { multi: true });
   } 
});

createMessageAlert = function(messageId, roomId, message){
      if ( message.user !== Meteor.userId() ){     
         Alerts.insert({
            userId        : message.userId,
            roomId        : Router.current().params._id,
            messageId     : messageId, 
            read          : false
         }, function(error, result){
               if( error ) 
                    console.log( error );
               if( result ) 
                    console.log( 'alert attached, alertId: ' + result );
                    //returns an alertId in my case
         });
         console.log('alert#: ' + Alerts.find().count()); //returns 0
      }
};
```

Comment: Did you check if there are any Alerts in the collection on the server side? Maybe something is preventing you from adding the alerts or there might be a pub sub issue. Latency compensation can make it seem something is added but in actuality it might be disallowed and the change reversed.

Comment: Code looks ok. Is the data there in mongoDb at server? Is the subscribe handle ready?

Comment: Are you signed in?

Comment: The console log i have was in the collection.js (i.e both server and front end can access). That returned a valid alert Id insertion. Im signed in. In the console, typing in `Alerts.find().fetch();` returns `[ ]`, `Alerts.find().count(); returns 0`.

Comment: The console log i have was in the collection.js (both server & frontend can access). That returned a valid alert Id insertion but yet returns 0 count for alerts. Im signed in. In the console, typing in 'Alerts.find().fetch();' returns '[ ]', 'Alerts.find().count();' returns 0. However if I tweak publish to just 'Alerts.find(); instead of the userId conditions, the alerts count shows what I guess is all messages entered. How do I only count alerts unread?

Comment: I think you are nearly there. Please remove the userid condition from the pub part and run Alerts.find().fetch() in the browser console to see what is in the db Right now. From there you should do some experimenting with conditions in pub and helper